# Scala type variance example

Tags: scala

Following example is taken from Programming in Scala,2nd Edition. 
My doubt is why there are two flips as mentioned in the below statement "The type U inside this argument is again in positive position (two flips)"?

meow method result parameter position is +. So Cat[U,T] in Cat[Cat[U,T],U] will have - position since in Cat class's type parameter T is declared -ve.

The rule says that in C[Arg], the classification of Arg will be flipped if C's type parameter is declared - like C[-Q]

Applying that rule U which should be - will be flipped to + . So there is only flip. How come two flips for U as mentioned in the paragraph taken from the book?

```
  abstract class Cat[-T, +U] {

    def meow[W−](volume: T−, listener: Cat[U+, T−]−)
    : Cat[Cat[U+, T−]−, U+]+

 }
```

> The positions of the type parameter, W, and the two value parameters, volume and listener, are all negative. Looking at the result type of meow, the position of the first Cat[U, T] argument is negative, because Cat’s first type parameter, T, is annotated with a -. The type U inside this argument is again in positive position (two flips), whereas the type T inside that argument is still in negative position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U` is in a negative position for `Cat[U, T]`, which is itself in a negative position for `Cat[Cat[U,T],U]`. And two negatives give a positive here just like `(-1)*(-1) == 1`. It should be easy to realize why: consider two types `A` and `B` such that `B` is a subtype of `A` (`B <: A` for short). Then `Cat[B, T] >: Cat[A, T]` for any type `T` (that's just what contravariance means). Then `Cat[Cat[B, T], S] <: Cat[Cat[A, T], S]`. That's it.